# Что такое lazy initialization в отношении загрузки модулей?

Tags: javascript

Привет.
Проясните ситуацию с этим принципом.Насколько я понял это загрузка модуля ,когда он действительно нужен.
Как это реализируется на реальных проэктах?

**UPD:**
Автолоадер наш загрузчик файлов?В js плохо реализована эта задача.Кто-то знает хорошие загрузчики файлов?Я лишь встречал только немного теории чрез создание динимачиского тега.Я правильно понимаю что если есть у нас набор классов,так мы сначала создаем первый объект а потом вызываем подключение другого файла ,который содержит следующий класс и т д?

Comment: для jquery есть lazy плагин, но там тупо, ты объявляешь какие исходники какому методу .method() и при вызове этого метода грузится исходник и метод выполняется еще раз.

Comment: нужно посмотреть.Почему так мало ифнформации по этой теме в инете??

Comment: не очень нужно в js. но по желанию можно организовать загрузку конечно... правда будет весьма ограниченное применение

Answer (score 2):

На реальных проектах это реализуется с помощью автолоадера(чаще всего)
Вы мало того что инициализируете объект только при первом обращении к нему, так еще и необходимые файлы грузите только в этот момент.

Comment: погоди... автолоадер в javascript ?

Comment: ммм?

    var scr = document.createElement('script');
    scr.src = "file.js";

...

Comment: и где тут автолоадер ? лоадер вижу.

Comment: автолоадер был бы возможен, если бы событие onerror чуть более формальным было.